# Saving location to server in a given interval when app is in background. Long running service vs AlarmManager

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have an application where I want to collect users location whenever the application is put in the background. While application is in background I want to save location to server with a given intervall, like 15 min. What is the best way to do it? I have tried doing it with a long running service, but the annoying thing with the service is that it dies if system kills application due to lack of resources. I want the application to only stop collecting location if user removes it from "recent application" or Force quits it in another way. I have now set it up with an Alarm triggering a service(which stops itself after doing its location thing), but the Alarm also will be killed when lack of resources, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `Service.startCommand()` returned values :

[Service.START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

[Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)

These constants will allow the System to restart the service if needed. If the system does not restart it, it's a **very very bad practice** to do it : if the system freed some memory, you will probably miss some RAM to run your service ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks! I actually looked into it, and did use START_STICKY, but it still didnt really restart after app was killed. Okey, so it is very bad practice to keep to force it to "live" somehow then? I guess its better to just let it get killed. Switched to using AlarmManager instead to try to reduce used resources.

Comment: you question stated about "restarting a service killed by the System". you also tell us that you want your service to be actually killed when the user "I want the application to only stop collecting location if user removes it from "recent application" or Force quits it in another way.". It's what you describe in your comment ;) Everything seems to be correct then. Alsom force something when the user explicitly asks to stop is pretty bad ;)

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing :p Yeah, I wanted the service to not die, or actually restart when system killed the app. But I want the service to die if the user actually kill it themselves. And the last thing works properly

Comment: and so, with the "START_STICKY", the system will restart the service, if possible, when it killed it ;)